# Nested query with AVG function and DATEADD in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nested

HI Experts i stuck with this query  for second day 
 I have 2 querys which selecting  parameters from one view

```
  --Query A
  SELECT [ITEM_TYPE]
      ,[ITEM_NAME]

      ,AVG([ACT_VOL])      
  FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[VT_TOTALS]
  WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 'A'
  AND PROD_VOL != '0'
  AND PROD_VOL IS NOT NULL
  AND START_DATETIME >=DATEADD(day,-1, '20120420')
  group by [ITEM_TYPE],[ITEM_NAME]

--Query B
  SELECT [ITEM_TYPE]
      ,[ITEM_NAME] 
     ,AVG([ACT_VOL])      
  FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[VT_TOTALS]
  WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 'A'
  AND PROD_VOL != '0'
  AND PROD_VOL IS NOT NULL
  AND START_DATETIME >=DATEADD(day,-7, '20120420')
  AND START_DATETIME <='20120420'
  group by [ITEM_TYPE],[ITEM_NAME]
```

results should be 
`A. [ITEM_TYPE], A.[ITEM_NAME], A. AVG([ACT_VOL]),B. AVG([ACT_VOL])`
Any help? 
I was trying to create nested query from them but cannot do it  it  does not want fork with where clause

Comment: Perhaps, in the second query it must be WHERE ITEM_TYPE ='B' instead of A.

Comment: no its same Item only difrense in them is how AVG calculated one shows average vol fol las 7 days first avg vol for last day where item type A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ITEM_TYPE,A,ITEM_NAME,A.avgA,B.avgB
FROM
(
    SELECT [ITEM_TYPE]
          ,[ITEM_NAME]
          ,AVG([ACT_VOL]) as avgA     
    FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[VT_TOTALS]
    WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 'A'
      AND PROD_VOL != '0'
      AND PROD_VOL IS NOT NULL
      AND START_DATETIME >=DATEADD(day,-1, '20120420')
    group by [ITEM_TYPE],[ITEM_NAME]
) A FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT [ITEM_TYPE]
          ,[ITEM_NAME] 
         ,AVG([ACT_VOL]) as avgB     
    FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[VT_TOTALS]
    WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 'A'
      AND PROD_VOL != '0'
      AND PROD_VOL IS NOT NULL
      AND START_DATETIME >=DATEADD(day,-7, '20120420')
      AND START_DATETIME <='20120420'
    group by [ITEM_TYPE],[ITEM_NAME]
) B on A.ITEM_TYPE=B.ITEM_TYPE and A.ITEM_NAME=B.ITEM_NAME
```

Comment: You need `FULL JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you ! With full join query shows proper answer! Thank you! you save my weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT [ITEM_TYPE]
   , [ITEM_NAME] 
   , AVG([ACT_VOL]) AVG_A,
   , AVG(CASE WHEN START_DATETIME <='20120420' THEN ACT_VOL END) AVG_B
FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[VT_TOTALS]
WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 'A'
  AND PROD_VOL != '0'
  AND PROD_VOL IS NOT NULL
  AND START_DATETIME >=DATEADD(day,-7, '20120420')
GROUP BY [ITEM_TYPE],[ITEM_NAME]
```

Comment: but  this case is not calculating anything

Comment: What do you mean? Can you demonstrate it on the http://sqlfiddle.com , it is very interesting.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov, sorry, I missed the `WHEN` keyword. Updated. The `but this case is not calculating anything` is confusing, because the query must throw error without `WHEN`.

Comment: could you please enplane case?

Comment: @AndreyIvanov, What do you mean?